# U-shaped Beta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm aware that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494530/why-does-the-beta-distribution-become-u-shaped-when-alpha-and-beta-1) is similar but for my taste, I   don't find intuitive. Why $\beta$ distribution is U shaped when $\alpha$, $\beta$ < 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\alpha^\prime:=2-\alpha,\,\beta^\prime:=2-\beta$, so a $\operatorname{B}(\alpha,\,\beta)$ distribution has PDF proportional to $x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$, while a $\operatorname{B}(\alpha^\prime,\,\beta^\prime)$ has PDF proportional to $x^{\alpha^\prime-1}(1-x)^{\beta^\prime-1}=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}$. In other words, the two PDFs are inversely proportional. Since $\alpha<1,\,\beta<1\implies\alpha^\prime>1,\,\beta^\prime>1$, we can take the more familiar shape for $\operatorname{B}(\alpha^\prime,\,\beta^\prime)$, then infer the shape for $\operatorname{B}(\alpha,\,\beta)$. For example, if $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$, one PDF is proportional to [the $U$-shape](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fsqrt%28x*%281-x%29%29+from+0+to+1) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$, the other to [the speed bump](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28x*%281-x%29%29+from+0+to+1) $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$.